# Is there an expected date for when Java data classes will be introduced?

Tags: java

Scala (case classes) and C# (structs) have support for data classes. When is Java expected to offer support for this language feature?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With a bit of reseach, I ended up with [Data Classes and Sealed Types for Java](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/amber/datum.html) by Brian Goetz.

Here is the [JEP](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/359), **Records (Preview)**, linking to the above.

Summary - It is just an idea/JEP. So, we cannot tell when it would be implemented (or if it would be implemented at all)

Answer (score 2):

The tentative date is [March 2020](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3436795/jdk-14-the-new-features-in-java-14.html) for the release of JDK 14.

In [Nov. 2019](https://jaxenter.com/java-14-update-news-163585.html), the [JEP 359](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/359) about **Records** (data carriers classes) has been confirmed as being part of Java 14 as a **[preview](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/12)** (meaning, as [commented below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58229594/is-there-an-expected-date-for-when-java-data-classes-will-be-introduced/58939556#comment104150238_58939556) by [Basil Bourque](https://stackoverflow.com/users/642706/basil-bourque), it needs to be enabled explicitly and it can be removed in the future).

Still: you can start *experimenting* with it starting with Java 14, March 2020.

As [presented here](https://dzone.com/articles/introducing-java-record), `record Range(int lo, int hi)` would replace

```
package javax0.geci.tests.record;

import javax0.geci.annotations.Geci;

@Geci("record")
public final class Range {

    final  int  lo;
    final  int  hi;

    //<editor-fold id="record">

    public Range(final int lo, final int hi) {
        this.lo = lo;
        this.hi = hi;
    }

    public int getLo() {
        return lo;
    }

    public int getHi() {
        return hi;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return java.util.Objects.hash(lo, hi);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Range that = (Range) o;
        return java.util.Objects.equals(that.lo, lo) && java.util.Objects.equals(that.hi, hi);
    }

    //</editor-fold>
}
```

Comment: @BasilBourque Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 2):

### March 2021

> Is there an expected date for when Java data classes will be introduced?

Yes: **mid-March 2021** given the 6-month cadence of the Java release train.

- **Java 16**

  - *Records* feature will officially ship in Java 16, if previews below succeed.
  - Expected 2021-03
- **Java 15**

  - [JEP 384: Records (Second Preview)](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/384)
  - Expected 2020-09-15 ([schedule](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk/15/))
- **Java 14**

  - [JEP 359: Records (Preview)](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/359)
  - Available now

## Java Records

The *Records* feature being previewed provide for “declaring classes which are transparent holders for shallowly immutable data”. In other words, a *nominal tuple*, a specific ordered sequence of elements.

Records are a special kind of class. In defining a record class, you trade away some flexibility for concision. Here is a complete example record class definition:

```
record Task( String title , String notes , LocalDate due ) {}
```

Or:

```
record Dog( Breed breed , Color color , String name ) {}
```

The compiler implicitly takes care of providing a constructor, member fields, accessor methods, `toString`, `hashCode`, and `equals`. You can optionally override these if desired, such as defining a constructor than validates the inputs.

For more info:

- [*Java 14 Feature Spotlight: Records*](https://www.infoq.com/articles/java-14-feature-spotlight/) by Brian Goetz, 2020-02

Answer (score -1):

Just make all attributes public and do not add any methods. Usually, it is not recommendable, but it behaves quite like a `struct`, I guess.

Comment: The question is about a different sense of "data class".